# Is this patent valid us20120228385?

Tags: prior-art, us20120228385

It seems to me that services like this http://www.greengym.ca/QRCODES.html
invalidate this patent.  Also, how is this an "invention".  Seems to be it shouldn't be a patentable item.

[link to patent application US20120228385](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120228385)

Answer (score 2):

This is an application for a patent, not a granted patent. It has been given an initial rejection as of Dec. 19th 2012 based partially on a patent application that uses RFID rather than an image capture to get the URL of the video. You can see what the applicant has already made the examiner aware of and what the exminer found in his/her search by looking this up in [Uspto public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)

**To be prior art something needs to actually be prior**. It is not clear that this greengym.ca service was public before this application was filed. I looked up this site at the wayback machine and the first time the qr code thing appears on the front page of their web site is in July 2001 with a big "NEW" banner. However the previous snapshot without it is back in April. This application has a priority date in March 2001. If you have documentation putting the greengym before March 2011 you could consider, following this site's FAQs, filing it in the case yourself. Free for up to three documents.